# In magento, how can we bring the swatch options of a configurable product and it's corresponding image url's in an array?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, configurable-product, ajax

I need to bring the swatch options of a configurable product and its corresponding image url's stored in an array in PLP page in magento. How can I do that?

I got an empty image url array while trying. Used js: vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

Comment: You should share what approach you tried so far and the issue you are facing